# Error deploying SharePoint 2013 app to preview account

Tags: 2013

I've downloaded some of the sample apps for SharePoint 2013. After changing the site URL, I tried deploying the app to my SharePoint 2013 preview account.

After waiting a while (first uninstalling, then installing) the following error is thrown:

"The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found".

In the meantime, something did happen. The app was actually deployed in SharePoint. When I now try to open the app, it redirects to localhost which isn't started yet, with a page not found as a result (seems fair). So I manually start the local IISExpress instance; return to the app in SharePoint and try again: works.

So all the bits seem to be deployed ok, but somehow the debug process doesn't work quite right. It could have something to do with our proxy server, as I had some other problems with that too. But I tried setting it explicitely (as opposed to a config script), didn't help. Also; the requests are send out fine when I check with Fiddler. But one set of requests does seem to be recurrent a few times before failing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> it simply asks the Operating System to perform all Name Resolution,
>   and this error is being returned by the Operating System to the
>   software.  Therefore, if you're entering the computer's name (its
>   hostname or fully qualified domain name), try using the IP address
>   instead.  This should resolve the issue in most cases.

I guess there is some problem with name resolution.

[Source of Information](http://kb.realvnc.com/questions/112/I%27m+receiving+the+error+%22The+requested+name+is+valid,+but+no+data+of+the+requested+type+was+found+%2811004%29.%22)

Comment: ? If that was the case, it shouldn't deploy to SharePoint alltogether right? Which is quite obviously does.

Comment: SharePoint is quiet unpredictable, there's so many things going on for one single event that you can't really assume what's actually went wrong, but I just assumed it could be name resolution problem or network related problem by looking at error :)

Comment: Yes that's what Google says. But it doesn't get me closer to a solution, and to get to a solution you first have to get to the origin of the fault. But thanks nonetheless.